# android pause an image

Tags: android, image, slideshow

hi to all 
im using this to display images the screen

```
 ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

and this

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageview"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:scaleType="center"
  />
```

my question is how can make it pause for a couple of seconds then switch to the next image 
like the slideshow ....

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Implement a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). Here is more about updating the [UI from a timer](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)